# Setting a object property by variable ends up in an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple model base

```
class Model:

    _fields = {}

    def __init__(self, **props):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        for key, value in props.items():
            if key in self._fields:
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name not in self._fields:
            return
        setattr(self, name, value)
```

However, when I set a value that is in my `_fields` list, it ends up in an infinite loop (`setattr` calling `__setattr__`). I can't figure out how I can set a value like this.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the doc on [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), if `__setattr__` needs to set an attribute you can avoid recursion by calling the base class's `__setattr__` method:

```
object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

# Or ...
super().__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Comment: Ah, so if this is inherited, I have to create a `__setattr__` in each subclass? I can't just utilize it in the child?

Comment: @Rohit: `__setattr__` gets inherited like any other method. I'm not sure I understand your question. The point of this is that your `__setattr__` must call a *different* `__setattr__` in order to not be recursive.